# Hide notifications for flutter_background_service

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to hide the [notifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnsgf.jpg) running in the foreground? I know I can disable the permissions for notifications but does flutter_background_service provide that option and just run that in the background without showing anything?

```
 Future<void> initializeService() async {
  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
  await service.configure(
    androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
      onStart: onStart,
      autoStart: false,
      isForegroundMode: true,
    ),
    iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
      autoStart: false,
      onForeground: onStart,
    ),
  );

  service.startService();
}
```

My onStart()

```
 Future<void> onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
  DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();
     service.on('stopService').listen((event) {
        service.stopSelf();
      });
      LocationController lC = Get.put(LocationController());
      // bring to foreground
      Timer.periodic(const Duration(minutes: 15), (timer) async {
        if (service is AndroidServiceInstance) {
 if (await service.isForegroundService()) {
        lC.apiCallForEvery5min();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by using `FlutterBackgroundService().invoke('setAsBackground')` in my location controller. Then in my onStart(), I remove the line `if (await service.isForegroundService()) {}`.

Comment: The `setAsBackground` depends on which Android version you are using. For Android 12 and above, notification can be hidden. As for Android 11 and below, notification cannot be hidden.